# why does git mergetool say "No files need merging"?

Tags: git

I'm trying to configure BeyondCompare4 as my difftool and mergetool in git. I'm using git version 2.5.0.windows.1. So far BeyondCompare4 is working just fine as a difftool but not as a mergetool.

From my master branch I run `git mergetool branch3` and it responds with `No files need merging`

But when I run `git diff branch3` I can see several types of differences in one file (often on the same line). And if I just run `git merge branch3` it does start the merge process and stop with a CONFLICT. So why doesn't `git mergetool` work for me in the same way?

This link suggested `git config --global core.trustctime false` which I tried with no luck:
[git mergetool reports "No files need merging"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854611/git-mergetool-reports-no-files-need-merging)

This link suggested rerere may be a problem so I tried `git config --global rerere.enabled false` also with no luck:
[git tells me that I Merge conflict, but also tells me that no files need merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707104/git-tells-me-that-i-merge-conflict-but-also-tells-me-that-no-files-need-merging)

This is what my .gitconfig looks like:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc
[difftool]


    prompt = false
[difftool "bc"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = 'c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe' $LOCAL $REMOTE


[merge]
    tool = bc
[mergetool]
     prompt = false
[mergetool "bc"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = 'c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe' $LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED
```

I even tried modifying .gitconfig to change the bcomp4.exe path to something bogus just to see if I could get an error. If I make the change to difftool I get errors about the system not finding the path. But if I change it on the mergetool it just keeps saying "No files need merging" which leads me to believe BeyondCompare4 is not even running.

Thanks for any ideas why `git mergetool` is stopping early with that message.

Comment: what does "git status" show?

Comment: If you have `rerere` enabled, it could be some kind of bug between `rerere` and `mergetool`. I have successfully used following workaround: `git mergetool .` - note the extra period at the end!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `git mergetool` when you are in a state where you need to resolve conflicts, that is, after a merge results in a conflict.

```
git checkout master
git merge branch3
# the merge reports conflicts which we need to resolve
git mergetool
git add -u
git commit -m "a merge commit message"
```

More about resolving conflicts with meregetool can be found at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts

Consult `git help mergetool` for options.