# git mergetool says there is nothing to merge (but there is!)

Tags: git, mergetool

Say I have a file and I have two branches: `master` and `anotherbranch`.

The current situation is that  from the point of divergence, master branch has one commit (say a line in the file says "This is master") and the "anotherbranch" branch also has a commit (the same line says "this is another").

Obviously if you checkout master and do git merge there is going to be conflict and you can solve it by solving the conflict and commiting the branch.

But now I want to try the `git mergetool` tool so I checkout master and I do:

```
git mergetool

This message is displayed because 'merge.tool' is not configured.
See 'git mergetool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git mergetool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
tortoisemerge emerge vimdiff
No files need merging
```

Anyway disregard the first part (I solved that by configuring the tool) but notice the last line **No files need merging**

What? no files need merging. Well that is simply not true. The file needs merging
so why is this not working?

Comment: Did you checked out both branches before `git merge master` ?

Comment: I did not do `git merge master`. I am trying to learn to use `mergetoool`

Comment: You first have to run e.g. `git checkout master; git merge anotherbranch`, and then, in case there is a collision, run `git mergetool`.

Comment: @alfunx I am sorry, I don't understand what is the logic behind that. If I do `git merge` and solve the conflicts there is no need to do mergetool anymore. In fact I did the following before (following my book); `git checkout master`, then `git merge anotherbranch` and voila. Solved. There is no need for mergetool as you guys wrote. The thing is I want to use mergetool not merge

Comment: @KansaiRobot `git mergetool` is *not* some general purpose tool to perform merges, it is a tool that can help you solve conflicts. Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git

Comment: I understood now. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32290725/4451521). In the end, I managed to run mergetool and I have to report it is a very unuseuful "tool". Not planning to use it anymore

Comment: @KansaiRobot It is a very useful tool for me. I prefer to see conflicts as 2-way or 3-way diff in an editor, instead of the raw file with the Git conflict markers.