# Command line hangs and KDiff3 wont open with git mergetool

Tags: windows, git

PowerShell hangs after calling git mergetool and does not move on.

[image]

My global git config file

```
[user]
    name = scrubbed
    email = scrubbed@a.com
[credential]
    helper = manager
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = c:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = c:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707599/2348125