# git mergetool telling "No files need merging" instead of conflicting files

Tags: git, ubuntu, kdiff3

I was rebase master's branch to mine with following command

```
git rebase master
```

Then I got conflicts in many files. Then to resolve conflicts what I usually do is

```
git mergetool -t kdiff3
```

And usually I resolve conflicts with kdiff3. But this time mergetool is giving below output

```
No files need merging
```

But actually there are many files with conflicts. What I was expecting is it will show me a window to resolve conflicts.

Comment: Do you have `rerere` enabled ?

Comment: I imagine you have files showing up as "conflicting" in `git status` : open one of these files to see if there are any conflict markers

Comment: Yes there are conflict markers. But I don't want to resolve those conflicts all by hand.

Comment: Try a different diff tool. [Beyond Compare](http://scootersoftware.com) is a good one.

Comment: Hmmm. I will if I couldn't resolve the issue. BeyondCompare is paid tool. @axiac And I think kdiff3 was much powerful than it.

Comment: Did you have this problem from the very beginning for this rebase, or you have run git mergetool once and stepped over all files without resolving conflicts?

Comment: from very beginning when rebase stopped after showing that I have conflicts and I have to resolve them. @Leon

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the exact same situation few minutes ago and found at least two reasons, that you need to check to solve it:

1. Only file date has changed: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854611/git-mergetool-reports-no-files-need-merging)
2. File doesn't contain conflict markers (e.g. "<<<<<<<…") and shows a usual diff: It's a bit hidden, but if running `git rebase --continue` it tells you to simply add the file to the index (`git add <file>`).

(The second one solved my situation.)

In any case the "No files need merging" message appears, if there is no MERGE_HEAD file in the .git directory (don't touch that however). And so you can switch to whatever merge tool you like, but it won't help.

Cheers