# Git fails to merge even with no local changes

Tags: git, merge, conflict

When I downloaded changes from a remote to my local GIT repository via

```
git fetch
```

the status of my local repository was reported as

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded
```

which was quite obvious. Local changes or changes in the index were not listed. However, when I tried to do a fast forward by calling

```
git merge origin/master
```

I received the error message "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten" and one file was listed, which I indeed changed before. The strange thing is that it does not appear in the status report and so I cannot merge it with the remote version. Neither I can revert the changes since they are obviously not recognized.

In fact I, wonder how it is possible that no local changes are listed, but the merge fails due to local changes. The solution provided for a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074136/git-rebase-fails-your-local-changes-to-the-following-files-would-be-overwritte) did not help me, either.

Could anybody give me a hint on what could be the reason for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual command to fast-forward your local repository is `git pull`, not `git merge`. But I don't understand why merge would fail with that error messge either.

Comment: Stupid question, but did you actually commit your changes?

Comment: The actual point is that I did local changes to a file but after a `git status` the file is not listed as modified. So I cannot add anything to the index and hence cannot actually commit.
When I cloned the repository and made changes to the same file everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git fetch` first or `git pull` and then `git rebase`. Afterwards you should be able to do the merging